# what do (&p)[7] represent here?

Tags: c++, pointers

Can anyone please explain!
While referring **ArrayDecay**, I was stuck at this...,

```
void fun(int (&p)[7])
{
    cout << sizeof(p) << endl;
}
  
int main()
{
    int a[7] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,};
  
    cout << "Actual size of array is: ";
    cout << sizeof(a) <<endl;
  
    // Calling function by reference
    fun(a);
  
    return 0;
}
```

I know the difference between (*p)[] and *p[] and their functioning.
But, can't figure out what (&p)[] is!.

Comment: Ok, so `int *p` is a pointer to int, and `int &p` is a reference to int. `int (*p)[N]` is a pointer to an array of int of size N, hence `int (&p)[N]` is ...?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of function argument declarations, the `&` means *reference*.

So the function `fun` accepts one argument, which is a reference to an array of `7` integer elements.

The comment should have been a pretty big hint:

```
// Calling function by reference
fun(a);
```